# Why is my web application running under ASP.NET 4.0 when application pool is configured for ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, application-pool

I have configured a web application on IIS to use an application pool which is configured to use ASP.NET 2.0. I allocated this pool to this application. But when testing the application I noticed that it runs under ASP.NET 4.0 instead of ASP.NET 2.0.

This application is a child web application. The root application is also configured with an application pool which runs under ASP.NET 2.0

I checked the following things.

- Application pool correctly configured for ASP.NET 2.0
- Web application uses the right pool

  The root web application runs also under an Application pool which is configured for ASP.NET 2.0

The scenario described above occurs on one of the servers, on another one it works fine!
I've tried to find differences using Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, but no look so far.

Anyone an idea what prevents the application to run under ASP.NET 2.0?